# SSL certificate for azure cloudapp.net

Tags: azure, ssl, iis, https, certificate

I know that this question was asked many times but I couldn`t make it work with answers I found on web.

My goal is to make https://my.cloudapp.net to work. So solution for this, is to buy domain and certificate and make this domain point/redirect to my https://my.cloudapp.net. I bought lets say www.example.pl. Downloaded certificate from https://example.pl. Assigned certificate to https://my.cloudapp.net using IIS.

When I visit https://example.pl certificate itself is fine but firefox shows me error:

`my.cloudapp.net uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is only valid for the following names: example.pl, www.example.pl Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN`

What I`m doing wrong?

Edit Solution:
I called microsoft support and resolved the issue. The issue was on my domain provider side. My domain example.pl had forwarding wildcard *.example.pl to go to example.pl. Thats why when I made another forwarding from app.example.pl to my cloudapp it went straight to example.pl. Removed the wildcard and it started to working fine.

Comment: " Copied certificate from https://example.pl..." I don't understand what this means. Can you explain what you did there?

Comment: The part of “make this domain point/redirect to my https://my.cloudapp.net”is completely wrong. You should create a CNAME record on your DNS and point to the cloudapp.net address, instead. I believe all documentation points to that approach but you just missed.

Comment: By copied I mean I downloaded the certificate. By pointing I mean creating CNAME and A records.

Answer (score 0):

I attempt to visit the website https://example.pl, it works fine with IE edge or chrome explorer. Also i do a test over at the [Qualys SSL](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) Labs to check your certificate. It shows me  **Incorrect certificate because this client doesn't support [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)** and indicate that**This site works only in browsers with SNI support.** It is the browser issue. So you could try another explorer.

You can from [here](https://really-simple-ssl.com/knowledge-base/ssl_error_bad_cert_domain/) to get more details.

Comment: I cannot do that as certificate I got from www.example.pl contains only example.pl and www.example.pl domains and I cannot change them.

Comment: @user2279379, except the error, could you visit your real website? https://my.cloudapp.net is your web app in azure? Could you explain "Assigned certificate to https://my.cloudapp.net using IIS."?

Comment: Yes I can visit my real website. I don`t want to link my real website on web.I can do that in priv. By assigning I mean I downloaded pem file and private key from my domain provider. I used online tool to change from pem to pfx format. Copied it to my VM imported into IIS and used it to bind https on port 443.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173473/discussion-between-nancy-xiong-msft-and-user2279379).